# referencing non nested lists within a single variable

Tags: python

I have a variable that is comprised of lists that are NOT nested

```
 myvariable = [list1][list2][etc]
```

I just cant figure out how to reference the different lists within the variable. `myvariable(0)` gives an error of list object not callable. obviously nested for loops don't work, and I'm just completely out of ideas.

When I print out the variable, it prints everything as expected, but return only returns the first list.

I'm sorry if this is really obvious, but its been driving me crazy for days.

Thanks for your help.

edit

(sorry i dont know how to make the code appear on multiple lines)

```
[u'leicestershire', u'virginia', u'Lincs', u'tonyssoccerschool@yahoo', u'.', u'co', u'.', u'uk', u'cleethorpes', u'Grimsby', u'Usually', u'the', u'M25', u'?', u'Grimsby', u'Worldwide', u'Market', u'Rasen', u'Sheffield/Grimsby', u'United', u'States', u'Grimsby', u'Grimsby', u'Grantham', u',', u'Lincolnshire', u'south', u'london/grimsby', u'Grimsby', u'Cleethorpes', u'Lincoln', u',', u'England', u'Grimsby', u'UK', u'London', u',', u'UK', u'Preston', u'Grimsby', u'Lincolnshire', u',', u'UK', u'Swadlincote', u',', u'Derbyshire', u'Hexham', u',', u'Northumberland', u',', u'UK', u'Grimsby', u'Grimsby', u',', u'UK', u'Harrogate', u'Hexham', u',', u'Northumberland', u',', u'UK', u'356', u'Holderness', u'Road', u'-', u'Hull', u'Yorkshire', u',', u'via', u'the', u'M180', u'Grimsby', u'Eltham', u',', u'London', u'United', u'Kingdom', u'Leeds', u',', u'West', u'Yorkshire', u'.', u'London', u'Ross', u'Castle', u'UK', u'(based', u'in', u'Lincolnshire)', u'Wolverhampton', u'#wwfc', u'Little', u'Mountain', u',', u'United', u'States', u'Grimsby', u'Birmingham', u',', u'UK', u'usa', u'/', u'danville', u',', u'va', u'Free', u'Bets', u'-', u'cambridge', u'UK', u'Grimsby', u'Ireland', u'Grimsby', u'Some', u'club', u'..', u'Resides', u'Milton', u'Keynes', u'Dunstable', u'Beds', u'www', u'.', u'facebook', u'.', u'com/3StyleSports', u'London-Alicante', u'Grimsby', u'North', u'Lincolnshire', u'Grimsby', u',', u'England', u'Grimsby', u'Lincolnshire', u'Cleethorpes', u',', u'UK', u'Lincoln', u',', u'UK', u'.', u'England', u'Home', u'Counties', u'/', u'North', u'London', u'Gateshead', u'UK', u'Andalucia', u'Grimsby', u',', u'England', u'Hull', u'(Booo)', u'-', u'UK', u'United', u'Kingdom']
```

```
[u'Grimsby', u'Grimsby', u'Grimsby', u'cambridge', u'Grimsby', u'Lincoln', u',', u'UK', u'.', u'www', u'.', u'facebook', u'.', u'com/3StyleSports', u'North', u'Lincolnshire', u'Grimsby', u'Hull', u'(Booo)', u'-', u'UK', u'Wolverhampton', u'#wwfc', u'United', u'Kingdom', u'Grimsby', u'Lincolnshire', u',', u'UK', u'Grimsby', u',', u'England', u'London', u',', u'UK', u'Some', u'club', u'..', u'Birmingham', u',', u'UK', u'Grimsby', u'Worldwide', u'Sheffield/Grimsby', u'Grimsby', u',', u'England', u'UK', u'?', u'cleethorpes', u'Resides', u'Milton', u'Keynes', u'UK', u'Usually', u'the', u'M25', u'Cleethorpes', u'Grimsby', u'Swadlincote', u',', u'Derbyshire', u'Cleethorpes', u',', u'UK', u'England', u'Preston', u'Dunstable', u'Beds', u'Hexham', u',', u'Northumberland', u',', u'UK', u'Lincolnshire', u'Lincs', u'leicestershire', u'Little', u'Mountain', u',', u'United', u'States', u'Lincoln', u',', u'England', u'south', u'london/grimsby', u'tonyssoccerschool@yahoo', u'.', u'co', u'.', u'uk', u'Home', u'Counties', u'/', u'North', u'London', u'UK', u'(based', u'in', u'Lincolnshire)', u'virginia', u'Hexham', u',', u'Northumberland', u',', u'UK', u'Gateshead', u'Leeds', u',', u'West', u'Yorkshire', u'.', u'Grimsby', u',', u'UK', u'London-Alicante', u'Yorkshire', u',', u'via', u'the', u'M180', u'Grimsby', u'Eltham', u',', u'London', u'United', u'Kingdom', u'Ireland', u'usa', u'/', u'danville', u',', u'va', u'London', u'United', u'States', u'Harrogate', u'Grimsby', u'Grimsby', u'Grimsby', u'Ross', u'Castle', u'Market', u'Rasen', u'UK', u'Grimsby', u'356', u'Holderness', u'Road', u'-', u'Hull', u'Andalucia', u'Free', u'Bets', u'-', u'Grantham', u',', u'Lincolnshire', u'Grimsby'][u'London', u'East', u'London', u'&', u'Essex', u'Grimsby', u'bromley', u'uk', u'lincoln', u'Grimsby', u'Grimsby', u',', u'England', u'Great', u'Great', u'Grimsby', u'Liverpool', u'New', u'Waltham', u'Derby', u'Washington', u'DC', u'USA', u'London', u'UK', u'Grimsby', u'liverpool', u'Great', u'Grimsby', u'London', u'\xdcT:', u'19', u'.', u'113285', u',', u'73', u'.', u'0078425', u'east', u'anglia', u'Cleethorpes', u'Somewhere', u'and', u'Anywhere', u'...', u'Here', u'west', u'midlands', u'Glasgow', u'London', u',', u'Crouch', u'End', u'Cottingham', u'Prague', u'Grimsby', u'Norwich', u',', u'England', u'Yorkshire', u',', u'UK', u'Cleethorpes', u'Grimsby', u'Stavanger', u'Grimsby', u'Grimsby', u'cleeeeeeethorpes', u'!', u'Dublin', u',', u'Dundee', u',', u'Humberside', u'Leicester', u'Omnipresent', u'Grimsby', u'Goodison', u'Park', u',', u'Liverpool', u'.', u'GB', u'Lisbon', u'Lincolnshire', u'Norfolk', u'London', u'Cardiff', u',', u'Wales', u'Grimsby', u'Immingham', u',', u'England', u'Grimsby', u',', u'UK', u'.', u'Grimsby', u'Grimsby', u'Near', u'Yorkshire', u'Newcastle', u'North', u'East', u',', u'England', u'Lincoln', u'Cornwall', u',', u'UK', u'Grimsby', u'london', u'town', u'baby', u'London', u'London', u'Town', u'Cleethorpes', u',', u'Lincolnshire', u'Great', u'Grimsby', u'Rawtenstall', u',', u'Rossendale', u'Cleethorpes', u'NEC', u',', u'Birmingham', u'Facebook', u'Page', u'London', u'Grimsby', u'RIght', u'here'][u'Cleethorpes', u'Leeds', u'Grimsby', u'Grimsby', u'Caistor', u',', u'Lincolnshire', u'Surrey', u'Grimsby', u',', u'UK', u'Preston', u'Hong', u'Kong', u'Grimsby', u',', u'United', u'Kigdom', u'Stallingborough', u'Lincolnshire', u',', u"it's", u'ace', u'!', u'grimsby', u'Great', u'Coates', u'Ireland', u'iPhone:', u'50', u'.', u'695671', u',', u'-1', u'.', u'291476', u'grimsby', u'uk', u'Yorba', u'Linda', u'grimsby', u'Lincoln', u',', u'UK', u'Sheffield', u',', u'UK', u'.', u'Manchester', u',', u'England', u'Grimsby', u',', u'NE', u'Lincolnshire', u',', u'UK', u'skegness', u'N/E', u'Lincolnshire', u'Brisbane', u',', u'Australia', u'leafy', u'cheshire', u'Grimsby', u',', u'UK', u'South', u'Killingholme', u'North', u'Pole', u'(well', u',', u'I', u'was', u'...', u')', u'England', u'Immingham', u'.', u'London', u'Knutsford', u'Off', u'Spurn', u'Head', u'grimsby', u'Cleethorpes', u'Yorkshire', u'Bath', u',', u'UK', u'Grimsby', u'Derby', u',', u'UK', u'The', u'dirty', u'South', u'of', u'England', u'costa', u'del', u'grimsby', u'hull\n', u'At', u'Home', u'or', u'Work', u'Grimsby', u'Cleethorpes/Nottingham', u'grimsby', u',', u'uk', u'.', u'chelsea', u'fan', u'Immingham/Louth', u'via', u'Sunderland', u'Brigg', u'/', u'Grimsby', u'/', u'High', u'Wycombe', u'Grimsby', u'Immingham', u',', u'UK', u'Grimsby', u',', u'Lincolnshire', u'Louth', u',', u'Lincolnshire', u'habrough', u'grimsby', u'Reading', u'immingham', u'Grimsby', u'Liverpool', u'Stafford', u'Grimsby', u'Cleethorpes', u'Grimsby', u'Cleethorpes', u'\xdcT:', u'53', u'.', u'549088', u',', u'-0', u'.', u'087738', u'Grimsby', u'Grimsby', u'.', u'uk', u'Grimsby', u'Lincoln', u'Trapped', u'in', u'Doncaster', u'Grimsby', u'Grimsby', u',', u'Lincolnshire', u'Moomin', u'Valley', u'UK', u'Mablethorpe', u',', u'Lincolnshire', u'China', u'all', u'round', u'the', u'globe'][u'Grimsby', u',', u'UK', u'Derbyshire', u'Leeds', u',', u'West', u'Yorkshire', u'Manchester', u'Great', u'Grimsby', u'Grimsby', u'United', u'Kingdom', u'UK', u'Laceby', u'UK', u'Grimsby', u'Aspiring', u'author/poet']
```

the second code block, is everything contained within the variable, i think it is 3 un nested lists.

the first code block is what is returned by return

edit2

the code that creates this

```
   for l in locations:
            Lexer.input(l)
            for ll in Lexer:
                locations1.append(ll.value)
```

edit 3

when i use a nested for loop on this code, it doesnt loop through each list and then each word in the list, it instead loops over every word in the first list and then every letter in each word.

im honestly trying to give as much detail as i can, im sorry if im explaining the problem badly.

edit 4

```
return locations1
```

(is what returns the first block)

```
self.response.out.write(locations1)
```

what prints out the second block)

Comment: I don't understand what `[list1][list2][etc]` is at all. As for `myvariable(0)`- is `myvariable[0]` what you're looking for?

Comment: Can you post your real code? The example line above doesn't make sense. You're getting the callable error because you don't use `(0)` notation to look up items from arrays, you use the `[0]` notation.

Comment: I can assure you that you don't have the structure you think you're describing. Please show `repr()` output.

Comment: Did you mean a `tuple()` perhaps? `myvariable = list1, list2, etc` creates a `tuple`, a non-mutable list. Use it just like any other Python sequence; `myvariable[0]`, etc.

Comment: Please post actual code that demonstrates your problem. Your description is neither correct nor helpful. Variables are not "comprised of lists"; they are names that reference specific objects. What object does `myvariable` refer to?

Comment: i have edited the question to show what the variable contains.  it is not a list of lists, it is a variable that contains i suppose you would call them inline lists. myvariable = [ this is list 1] [this is list 2] [this is list 3]  i have never come across this kind of data structure before.

Comment: @tanky: Your comment is _still_ not code you could have possibly written without getting an immediate exception, and the same goes for your updated example. Paste real, running code. Print out real `repr` values and copy and paste them here. Otherwise, we're stuck guessing.

Comment: `im honestly trying to give as much detail as i can` don't worry about it, just don't get frustrated =). For future questions try posting a piece of code that can be copy/pasted by other stackoverflow users, also include the outputs you are expecting. There is also a [post](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/03/rubber-duck-problem-solving.html) by Jeff Atwood on good question writing. Having said that can you copy and paste the exact line of code that assigns the lists to `myvariable` when I try and run `myvariable = [1,2,3][4,5,6][7,8,9]` I get an error.

Comment: Should that be `self.reponse` or `self.response`?

Comment: yes that should be self.response

Answer (score 2):

You claim that you have code like this:

```
myvariable = [list1][list2][etc]
```

This will not define three new "non-nested" or "inline" lists and store them in `myvariable` or anywhere else. What it will do is this:

- Create a single-element list, whose element is whatever value you have in `list1`.
- Look up the `list2`th element in that single-list.
- Look up the `etc`th element in the resulting thing.

In the case where `list2` happens to be the number 0 or -1, and `etc` happens to be an integer that's a valid index into whatever value you had in `list1`, this will return that value. Otherwise, it's just going to raise a `TypeError` or `IndexError`. (Well, there are some cases where a slice object would also work, but let's ignore that.) And, based on the name, presumably it's a list, which will raise the `TypeError`.

---

And most likely, you don't really have `list1`, `list2`, or `etc` anywhere, but something like this:

```
myvariable = ['a', 'b']['c', 'd']['e', 'f']
```

That will *definitely* raise a `TypeError`, because you're trying to use the tuple `'c', 'd'` as an index into the list `['a', 'b']`, and you can't do that.

---

One thing you *can* write is this:

```
myvariable = ['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['e', 'f']
```

What *that* does is to define a tuple made of three lists. This is a perfectly valid thing. And it works very similarly to a list of three lists. For example:

```
>>> myvariable[0]
['a', 'b']
>>> myvariable[0][1]
'b'
```

---

Another thing you can write is this:

```
myvariable = ['a', 'b']
['c', 'd']
['e', 'f']
```

This sets `myvariable` to `['a', 'b']`, and then defines two other lists just to immediately forget them.

So, you can use `myvariable` later to access the elements of the first list, because you've made it a name for that first list, but there's no way to access the elements of the other two lists, because you didn't store them anywhere.

---

Meanwhile, you claim that "the code that creates this" is:

```
for l in locations:
    Lexer.input(l)
    for ll in Lexer:
        locations1.append(ll.value)
```

Presumably there's a `locations1 = []` somewhere above this.

If so, you have a single list, `locations1`. There are no other lists to access at all.

---

Looking at your first example, which you call "inline lists":

```
[u'leicestershire', u'virginia', u'Lincs', u'tonyssoccerschool@yahoo', u'.', u'co', u'.', u'uk', u'cleethorpes', u'Grimsby', u'Usually', u'the', u'M25', u'?', u'Grimsby', u'Worldwide', u'Market', u'Rasen', u'Sheffield/Grimsby', u'United', u'States', u'Grimsby', u'Grimsby', u'Grantham', u',', u'Lincolnshire', u'south', u'london/grimsby', u'Grimsby', u'Cleethorpes', u'Lincoln', u',', u'England', u'Grimsby', u'UK', u'London', u',', u'UK', u'Preston', u'Grimsby', u'Lincolnshire', u',', u'UK', u'Swadlincote', u',', u'Derbyshire', u'Hexham', u',', u'Northumberland', u',', u'UK', u'Grimsby', u'Grimsby', u',', u'UK', u'Harrogate', u'Hexham', u',', u'Northumberland', u',', u'UK', u'356', u'Holderness', u'Road', u'-', u'Hull', u'Yorkshire', u',', u'via', u'the', u'M180', u'Grimsby', u'Eltham', u',', u'London', u'United', u'Kingdom', u'Leeds', u',', u'West', u'Yorkshire', u'.', u'London', u'Ross', u'Castle', u'UK', u'(based', u'in', u'Lincolnshire)', u'Wolverhampton', u'#wwfc', u'Little', u'Mountain', u',', u'United', u'States', u'Grimsby', u'Birmingham', u',', u'UK', u'usa', u'/', u'danville', u',', u'va', u'Free', u'Bets', u'-', u'cambridge', u'UK', u'Grimsby', u'Ireland', u'Grimsby', u'Some', u'club', u'..', u'Resides', u'Milton', u'Keynes', u'Dunstable', u'Beds', u'www', u'.', u'facebook', u'.', u'com/3StyleSports', u'London-Alicante', u'Grimsby', u'North', u'Lincolnshire', u'Grimsby', u',', u'England', u'Grimsby', u'Lincolnshire', u'Cleethorpes', u',', u'UK', u'Lincoln', u',', u'UK', u'.', u'England', u'Home', u'Counties', u'/', u'North', u'London', u'Gateshead', u'UK', u'Andalucia', u'Grimsby', u',', u'England', u'Hull', u'(Booo)', u'-', u'UK', u'United', u'Kingdom']
```

There's no `[` but the one at the start, and no `]` but the one at the end (not even inside quotes). This is just one big list.

And therefore:

> when i use a nested for loop on this code, it doesnt loop through each list and then each word in the list, it instead loops over every word in the first list and then every letter in each word.

That's exactly what you'd expect for a single list of strings. (A string is itself a sequence of one-character strings.) Which is very good evidence that, whatever you *think* you have, what you *actually* have is just a single list of strings.

Comment: Good answer, I suppose there is also a possibility that something like `myvariable = [list] + [list2]` was used.

Comment: thanks, i appreciate your help. however, if you look at the 2nd example, you will see that it starts with a single square bracket and if you scroll through about 2/3s of it, you will see that 1 list is closed and another one is opened directly behind. and then when you get to the end of the second example you will see that the whole thing is closed with a single square bracket. and when i try to use a nested for loop on that, it only loops over the first list, and then loops over the letters.  thanks again for your help

Comment: @tanky: What do you mean "try to use a nested loop on that"? "That" isn't actual code with a loop, assignment, or anything else. It's just an expression—and, as I showed in my answer, an expression that will raise a `TypeError` if you try to evaluate it. Is that an excerpt from your source code? Output from running some code you haven't shown us? A file you're reading in some way?

Comment: Hold on… From your last edit to the question, are you saying the second one is the contents of some file after you call `self.response.out.write(locations1)`? That would only work if `locations1` were a _string_, not a _list_ (unless `response.out` isn't actually a file-like object, just some object with a completely-unrelated `out` method). So, your problem isn't about one list vs. multiple lists, it's about a string that happens to look like the repr of a list (or multiple lists). Where does this string come from? How do you build it up? What are you expecting to do with it?

Answer (score 0):

Try `myvariable[0]` with square brackets.

```
>>> myvariable = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
>>> myvariable[0]
[1, 2, 3]
>>>
```

Comment: thanks, but it is not a list of lists, its is just lists, im struggling to explain it but i have entered edited the question to show what the code returns.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a collection of lists in a single variable it must be the case that there is at least one layer of nesting. The outer iterable need not be a list per se (it could be a tuple or some other iterable), but it is nevertheless a container of lists. You're trying to access it with subscripts (parentheses are not actually valid for subscripts, but based on the fact you used an integer I assume you were *going for* subscripts), so presumably you actually do have a list of lists, even if the *inner* lists aren't themselves nested further.

```
>>> myvariable=[['a'],['list', 'of'],['Liszts']]
>>> print myvariable[1]
['list', 'of']
```

If your iterable is actually a generator you actually can't access them with subscripting and will have to access them one at a time by calling `next()` or convert the thing whole-hog into a list of lists.

Comment: *waits patiently for explanation of downvote.*

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I'm guessing someone did because you posted a solution for a nested list although the OP claims not to have one.

Comment: @chepner yes, well, I've explained myself, which is more than I can say for the downvoter.

Comment: all i can say is i have edited my code to show, what created it and what the variable looks like.